# andengine move sprite blocked on corner

Tags: andengine

I've a sprite in physicworld not registered with touchArea, it moves only when collides with other sprites and bounce regularly on physicworld border. Now I'm trying to move it randomly also when is not collided.
I try to give it a linear velocity but it moves till the lower right corner and stay there without bouncing back

```
if(Sprite.getX() > 0) {
    bodySprite.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(VELOCITY_X, VELOCITY_Y));
} else if(Sprite.getX() + Sprite.getWidth() > CAMERA_WIDTH) {
    bodySprite.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-VELOCITY_X, -VELOCITY_X));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure that `Sprite.getX() + Sprite.getWidth() > CAMERA_WIDTH` is ever true? (Taking into account rotation, etc...)

I'd rather put some kind of box2d sensor at the screen edges and when they begin touching, apply an impulse.

Comment: I have wallFixtureDef (0, 0.5f, 0.5f) applied to my screen edges, and all sprites bouncing back from edges well. l would like to keep the sprites always in movement, avoiding they stop.

Comment: I change LinearVelocity with:Vector2 shoot = new Vector2((originX - fingerX), (originY - fingerY));
body.setLinearVelocity(shoot);
Now sprite moves exactly to the position I want, but too speedy. How can I set speed value?

Comment: Multiply the vector by some value < 1, then it get's slower (shorter).